# Powershell divide a string into parts ans put parts into different variables

Tags: powershell

PowerShell script to split the path 
  I have String as below:

```
refs/remotes/origin/CS-38123     Shreya Gopal    Mon Jan 8 12:38:20 2018 -0600
```

I want PowerShell script to put the above string in different variables like

```
$ticket = 'refs/remotes/origin/CS-38123'
$author = 'Shreya Gopal'
$time   = 'Mon Jan 8 12:38:20 2018 -0600'
```

can anyone suggest please

Comment: Show your effort mate. You can start using -split function to split the sentence based on the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string has at least two spaces separating the ticket, author and time fields, you could use a RegEx to parse the string and then assign to variables. eg.

```
$string = "refs/remotes/origin/CS-38123     Shreya Gopal    Mon Jan 8 12:38:20 2018 -0600"

$parsed = $string | select-string "(\S+)\s{2,}(.+?)\s{2,}(.+)"

$ticket = $parsed.matches[0].groups[1].value
$author = $parsed.matches[0].groups[2].value
$time   = $parsed.matches[0].groups[3].value
```

The RegEx captures 3 sections separated by blocks of 2 or more spaces.

Analysis of the RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/2Utvyw/1